# Counting Number of Documents in a Firestore Subcollection Using Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Have been trying to get the total number of documents available within a Firestore subcollection using Flutter using the count() method without much luck.  I'm basically reading each top collection ("a") document fields and then trying to read the number of documents available within the inner collection ("b").  This will all appear on a ListView widget.

The code below shows the last iteration of this code.  The code at issue is the last line shown.  Everything else works fine, but retrieving the number of documents for the inner collection "b" results in lots of reads from Firestore and not much else.

Note that I'm not getting any error of this code, but the value of collCount stays at 0 even though collection "b" does contain values.  Help is very much appreciated!!!

```
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("Title"),
    ),
    // Start of StreamBuilder...
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("a")
      .orderBy("date_time", descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // Start of ListView Builder...
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
            int collCount = 0;
            doc.reference.collection("b").count().get().then((value) => collCount = value.count);
...
```

Comment: The code to get the count from the subcollection looks fine at first glance. Did you try printing the value you get: `doc.reference.collection("b").count().get().then((value) => print('${value.count}));`? If that prints the correct value, the problem is likely in what you do with `collCount`.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen! Appreciate your response! And you're completely right. A print statement within then() shows the right values. So the question is how to get those values out within StreamBuilder(). Ended up using FutureBuilder() to extract the "count" value and embed it within a Text() widget. Lots of thanks!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @ajam.  --- It might be good to post your solution as an answer below. Self-answering is encouraged on Stack Overflow as that way others are more likely to find it going forward, and you can also accept it to bring closure to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of thanks to @FrankvanPuffelen!  Ended up replacing the

```
doc.reference.collection("b").count().get().then((value) => collCount = value.count);
```

line with a FutureBuilder statement below directly returning a Text widget with the *count* value, as shown below.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: doc.reference.collection("b").count().get(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AggregateQuerySnapshot> snapshot2) {
        if (snapshot2.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot2.data!.count.toString());
        }
        return Text("0");
    }
),
```